# In a column of a dataframe, count number of elements on list starting by "a"

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset like

```
data = {'ID':  ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value',
                'fourth_value', 'fifth_value', 'sixth_value'],
        'list_id': [['001', 'ab0', '44A'], [], ['005', '006'],
                    ['a22'], ['azz'], ['aaa', 'abd']]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I want to create two columns:

1. A column that counts the number of elements that start with "a" on 'list_id'
2. A column that counts the number of elements that DO NOT start with "a" on "list_id"

I was thinking on doing something like:

```
data['list_id'].apply(lambda x: for entity in x if x.startswith("a")
```

I thought on counting first the ones starting with “a” and after counting the ones not starting with “a”,  so I did this:

```
sum(1 for w in data["list_id"] if w.startswith('a'))
```

Moreover this does not really work and I cannot make it work.
Any ideas? :)

Comment: you have more items in `list_id` than `ID`, can you explicit how the dataframe looks like?

Comment: You should store scalars, not sequences in your dataframe. This becomes a lot easier when you do that.

Comment: please double check if my edit is correct

Comment: actually I have sequences on my dataframe, so the edit is not totally correct, but is fine, i will try to manipulate my dataframe to make it work as the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
             ID          list_id
0   first_value  [001, ab0, 44A]
1  second_value               []
2   third_value       [005, 006]
3  fourth_value            [a22]
4   fifth_value            [azz]
5   sixth_value       [aaa, abd]
```

you can use:

```
sum(1 for l in data['list_id'] for x in l if x.startswith('a'))
```

output: `5`

If you rather want a count per row:

```
df['starts_with_a'] = [sum(x.startswith('a') for x in l) for l in df['list_id']]
df['starts_with_other'] = df['list_id'].str.len()-df['starts_with_a']
```

*NB. using a list comprehension is faster than `apply`*

output:

```
             ID          list_id  starts_with_a  starts_with_other
0   first_value  [001, ab0, 44A]              1                  2
1  second_value               []              0                  0
2   third_value       [005, 006]              0                  2
3  fourth_value            [a22]              1                  0
4   fifth_value            [azz]              1                  0
5   sixth_value       [aaa, abd]              2                  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas something quite similar to your proposal works:

```
data = {'ID':  ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value', 'fourth_value', 'fifth_value', 'sixth_value'],
        'list_id': [['001', 'ab0', '44A'], [], ['005', '006'], ['a22'], ['azz'], ['aaa', 'abd']]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["len"] = df.list_id.apply(len)

df["num_a"] = df.list_id.apply(lambda s: sum(map(lambda x: x[0] == "a", s)))
df["num_not_a"] = df["len"] - df["num_a"]
```